# Как правильно верстать такую секцию?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сверстать такой элемент?

Comment: `<fieldset>`, `<legend>` и гугл вас спасут.

Comment: Лучше удалить вопрос(иначе минусы неизбежны) или задать вопрос конкретнее и приложить код,что Вы пытались сделать

Comment: @Александр, ты прав, но иногда бывают вопросы, что лучше картинку показать, чем объяснить.....  И как он должен привести промер, если он не знает каким образом это сделать?

Comment: @Air Например, конкретнее: как сверстать белую рамку с заглавием(посещение нашего сайта) и тп

Comment: @Александр согласет... При жлании можно все...  )))  Но картинка быстрее..)

Comment: @Air это я после англ.версии таким стал,там уже закрыли бы либо фура дизлайков подъехала бы...

Comment: Мы русские, терпимее...)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Blocks</legend>
  <div>Block</div>
  <div>Block</div>
  <div>Block</div>
</fieldset>
```